# Spreadsheet filter multiple values (comma sep)

Tags: filter, google-sheets

Hi how can I make the "FILTER" function to work if I have multiple parameters separates by comma.

```
FACTION   HERO
A         X
B         Y
A,B       Z
```

Now if I do a FILTER(B:B; A:A="A") the output will only be X. But Since Z is also in Faction A the output should be X and Z. How can I take care of this?

```
Wanted output     Actual output
X                 X
Z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways are:

```
=filter(B:B, regexmatch(A:A, "A"))

=QUERY( A:B , "Select B Where A contains 'A' " )
```